# Jquery ajax call getting 'error' with swagger rest api

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl

I used a swagger script to generate a rest api.

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  ...
},
"host": "localhost:8080",
"basePath": "/swagger-item-jaxrs",
"schemes": [ "http" ],
"consumes": [ "application/json" ],
"produces": [ "application/json" ],
"paths": {
"/item/{cd}": {
  "get": {
    "description": "Returns an item based on the item code passed.",
    "operationId": "findItemById",
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "application/xml",
      "text/xml",
      "text/html"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "cd",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "CD of item to fetch",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "item response",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/item"
        }
      },
      "default": {
        "description": "unexpected error",
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/errorModel"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
},
"definitions": {
"item": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "cd",
    "name"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "cd": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "tag": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
},
"errorModel": {
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "code",
    "message"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "code": {
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int32"
    },
    "message": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

I can call the api using the client generate java classes, I can even enter the url into the browser and get a response.

Browser: http://localhost:8080/swagger-item-jaxrs/item/0446840

Response: `{"cd":"0446840","name":"ROYAL BASMATI RICE  "}`

The Swagger UI can even get the same response back and indicates that the curl command is: `curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/swagger-item-jaxrs/item/0446840" -H  "accept: application/json"`

My ajax code:

`$.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/swagger-item-jaxrs/item/0446840"
      , method: "GET"
      , headers: { "accept": "application/json" }
     })
    .done(function(data) {
      alert('success');
      console.log('success: ');
      console.log(data);
    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      console.log('error: ');
      console.log(err);
    });`

Chrome developer tools console results:

`error:
Object {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible reasons that your code doesn't work:

1. The example swagger-file you provided is not valid. At least there should be one more `{`in the beginning. Since `$.ajax` automatically tries to parse, you need to make sure that you receive data in valid JSON.
   But it is possible to prevent $.ajax from parsing JSON. For this you need to add `dataType: "text"` to settings objects of $.ajax.
2. Using **localhost** causes issues as the security settings are different than
   accessing a normal website on the internet. Therefore i suggest that you use 
   the name of your machine and localhost.

In order to figure out what the issue is you need to see the error-text. Change your code like this: `console.log(err.statusText)`

You need to figure out if this error occurs on client or on server-side. Take a look at the log-file of your server. Can you see there your request ? What is the http status-code ?

Next: In google chrome/deveopler tools look at the network tab. Can you see request and response ?  Double clicking allows you to see all details. Can you see the response from the server ?

Then on the server you should try to change the logging level to trace or even debug. This allows you to see all details of your request.

Comment: I double checked the json swagger. I used the yaml in the Swagger Editor at http://editor.swagger.io/#!/ and downloaded the json and that is how it was generated. I added the dataType: "text", changed localhost to my machine name, and the console.log to err.statusText. All I get is the word 'error'.

Comment: I was able to get curl and run the curl command and it works. The only thing I cannot get to work at this point is from an ajax call, it goes to error and that is the only information given.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. I needed to add a function in my javascript to prevent the default submit.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to not having a prevent submit function in my javascript.
`$('#form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

Once this was added the page worked.